# How to fix CodeSign when it says user cancelled the operation? (And I didn't)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, codesign

I'm compiling an iPhone app meant to be Distributed. It's my first app so I followed the "iPhone Provisioning Profiles" instructions. Unfortunately it fails with this:

```
CodeSign build/*_*_.app
cd "/Users/videojuegos/Documents/*_*_"
setenv IGNORE_CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_RADAR_7181968 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: ******" "--resource-rules=/Users/videojuegos/Documents/*_*_/build/*_*_.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/Users/videojuegos/Documents/*_*_/build/Unity-iPhone.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/*_*_.xcent" "/Users/videojuegos/Documents/*_*_/build/*_*_.app"

/Users/videojuegos/Documents/*_*_/build/*_*_.app: The operation was cancelled by the user.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I thought Keychain wasn't allowing Codesign to work but as far as I can tell that isn't the case.

I also attempted running these commands from a terminal and it failed with this message:

```
Users/videojuegos/Documents/*_*_/build/Unity-iPhone.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/*_*_.xcent: cannot read entitlement data
```

I have made the xcode setting from scratch three times. Googled it. No results. I don't have any idea what else to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with `*_*_` being in the name and directory structure.  Why do you have it named that way? Are you trying to use a wild card or is it actually named that?  

I've never gotten that output from XCode before and not sure why you are building it / code signing in the terminal versus letting XCode build/codesign the distributed bundle.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the name of my app to "*_*_" because the company I work for states that I cannot give names of unannounced apps :/ Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If thats the case, you may want to double-check the output you pasted since I think you missed a spot.

you may also try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383981/im-looking-for-a-code-signing-tutorial-for-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: Did you solve this problem?  This just cropped up for me after adding a user to my provisioning profile and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entitlements value in the project build settings.  If so then delete it and try again